# MySQL phpmyadmin is changing values \/ = /

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to enter values into a database. Here is my query :

```
INSERT INTO `post_meta` (`id`, `post`, `extend`, `data`) VALUES
(1, 3, 1, '{"html":"<iframe src=\"http:\/\/tv.ccsd.net\/embed\/uz5tsdfwRIquKE\" width=\"512\" height=\"288\" seamless=\"seamless\"><\/iframe>"}');
```

but when I see the value in my database it is outputted as this:

```
{"html":"<iframe src="http://tv.ccsd.net/embed/uz5tsdfwRIquKE" width="512" height="288" seamless="seamless"></iframe>"}
```

How can I get phpmyadmin to stop doing this for this query. I have already went ahead and converted all the characters. Thanks!

In short, my goal is to keep the value as it was inserted, as the same in the database like this:

```
{"html":"<iframe src=\"http:\/\/tv.ccsd.net\/embed\/uz5tsdfwRIquKE\" width=\"512\" height=\"288\" seamless=\"seamless\"><\/iframe>"}
```

Comment: try with `htmlentities()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doing the right thing. The backslash is an escape character that tells MySQL to treat the next character literally. So `\/` means that a literal `/` character should be put in the data.

If you want a literal backslash to be put in the data, you need to escape the backslash:

```
INSERT INTO `post_meta` (`id`, `post`, `extend`, `data`) VALUES 
(1, 3, 1, '{"html":"<iframe src=\\"http:\\/\\/tv.ccsd.net\\/embed\\/uz5tsdfwRIquKE\\" width=\\"512\\" height=\\"288\\" seamless=\\"seamless\\"><\\/iframe>"}');
```

Comment: Thank you @barmar I'm not quite sure I understand, I'm just trying to add it in the database exactly how you see it in my "in short" summary. Does that make sense? I appreciate your help.

Comment: backslashes are used for input, they don't show up on output